# Jack doesn't seem to obfuscate the code by itself

Tags: android, proguard, android-jack-and-jill

I am using Android Studio version `v2.1.2` and `Proguard` doesn't work when I try to sign the release build, the build fails dramatically.

[According to this link from developer docs](https://source.android.com/source/jack.html) Jack does obfuscation automatically.

> Handles shrinking, obfuscation, repackaging and multidex Using a
>   separate package such as ProGuard is no longer necessary.

I had to disable `minifyEnabled` flag and remove the line where we load proguard file; to get it working, after doing this; I inspected the `apk` file generated by doing the above and I cannot tell whether Jack really obfuscated and reduced redundant code as the release `apk` size is same as the debug `apk` size.

I need to understand how to make obfuscation work with the newer compiler as the documentation doesn't really help.

I am looking forward to understand the following questions.

Does `Jack` work without `Proguard` file?

Is there a way to specify `Proguard` file?

Answer (score 2):

The Jack compiler has its own Shrinker and Obfuscator that re-uses existing Proguard rules (see [supported directives](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/jackandjill#TOC-Shrinking-and-Obfuscation-support)).

The configuration should be the same as before, so you need to add the following to your buildType configuration:

```
minifyEnabled true
proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
proguardFile 'your-proguard-file.txt'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.

I am still confused! Does Jack deobfuscate code on its own or does it need a Proguard file? If it accepts a proguardFile then what part of the obfuscation does it do on its own?

Comment: If the Jack toolchain is enabled, ProGuard is not executed at all. The specified proguard rules are evaluated and applied by the toolchain itself.